# How to create stored procedure for custom table type

Tags: sql-server

```
create proc ForCustomTable
(
    @FullName MyCustomTable READONLY
)
as
   set nocount on

   insert into @FullName
      select Fname, Lname 
      from addr
```

Getting error ........

How to solve this issue ?

Comment: ***WHAT*** error??!?!!? We can't read your screen, nor your mind - you'll have to **tell us!**

Comment: The error _should_ be obvious: you declared `@FullName` as `READONLY` and yet are trying to write to it. How to fix? Learn what Table-Valued Parameters (TVPs) are and what they are used for. Then if you still need help, you need to include in the question what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a [table valued parameter](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13782/table-valued-parameter-as-output-parameter-for-stored-procedure) to return data from a stored proc (as suggested by the keyword `READONLY`. You'll get the error

> The table-valued parameter "@FullName" is READONLY and cannot be modified.

There are many alternatives

- Return the result as a data set (i.e. just return `SELECT` data results)
- Insert the data into a #temp table - the #temp table will be available for the duration of the connection.
- Instead of using a Stored Proc, change it to a Table Valued Function and return the addresses from it

Comment: Why do you think that the O.P. is trying to return data via the TVP? It is possible that this person is trying to use it like an OUTPUT param, but there are too many things that are wrong with the posted code that intent cannot be inferred. And in fact, if you are correct about this persons intent, then the O.P. has such a fundamental misunderstanding of SQL Server stored procs that they won't be able to understand your answer ;-)